# Gaining root access on an Android phone exploited with MetaSploit

Tags: android, metasploit, root

I have been using `MetaSploit` for a while (3 years), and I have just started exploiting `Android`.

My `Android` has `root` access, and `SuperSu` is configured to 'grant' all `SU` requests.

I have the `payload` installed on my phone, but, whenever I try to use `POST` modules in `MetaSploit`, I get the message

```
This module requires root permissions
```

How would I get `root` permissions?

Comment: What exploit are you using exactly? can you put your Metasploit commands?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this will fail to show root

```
meterpreter> check_root
```

With one of the following outcomes:

> [+] Device is rooted
>
> [-] Device is not rooted

If the second, probably best to try

```
meterpreter> shell
```

> Process 1 created.
>
> Channel 1 created.

```
id
```

> uid=10005(u0_a5) gid=10005(u0_a5) groups=1015(sdcard_rw),1028((sdcard_r),3003(inet)

```
su
id
```

> uid=0(root) gid=0(root)

See more here -- http://blog.itselectlab.com/?p=6931

Comment: After su ``/system/bin/sh: <stdin>[2]: su: not found``

Comment: Install it from another device?

Comment: it was not rooted properly, sorry

Comment: When I run `shell`, it stuck on `Channel 1 created.`!

Comment: anyway, I get this: `/system/bin/sh: su: not found`